# How to save the index of a list item

Tags: python, python-2.7

Basically, how could I insert an element into a list at a specific position? For example, in the following, I remove a random element from a set and add it back in, but not in order. I know I can use bisect.insort for numbers, but what if I were using strings? Example:

```
>>> a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
>>> import random
>>> b = random.choice(a)
>>> a.remove(b)
>>> a
['one', 'two', 'four', 'five']
>>> b
'three'
>>> a += [b]
>>> a
['one', 'two', 'four', 'five', 'three']
```

I want to be able to place something back in at a specific location.

Comment: Why can't you use `list.insert(index, item)`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes and save the index before removing the element…

Comment: @elegant I'm unclear what you mean. Should I set the index of  b as another variable, c? If so, how do I find the index position of b?

Comment: @Mathime: Yes exactly. You could consider to use the `index()` method.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the index(position) of the element you want to enter, the command `list.insert(index,item)` will do what you want.

```
>>>numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
>>>import random
>>>removed = random.choice(numbers)
>>>index = numbers.index(removed)
>>>numbers.remove(removed)
>>>numbers.insert(index, removed)
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: In general, make sure you've done some Googling before posting a question to avoid downvotes and close-questions.  This is a pretty basic question--which is totally great--but most of those have already been answered or can be Googled in the docs.  If after some research you're still having trouble, come back and ask!